# Tag Graphics in ​is Protected

Tags: mathematica

The graph is not showing, I don't know what to do with: "Tag Graphics in​ is Protected"?

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 0):

Please restart your Mathematica kernel. You have set some of the symbols wrong earlier because there is no reason your code should not work

```
f[x_] = (Cos[x])/(x^2 - 2*x - 3);
d = Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 8}];
e = ListPlot[{{1, f[1]}}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]];
Show[d, e]
```

> [image: img]